# Hadoop DataNode not running in slave machine

Tags: hadoop, master-slave, datanode

Getting the below error in the datanode logs as shown in the screen shot. [image]
Tried formating the namenode and stop-all.sh -- start-all.sh. No luck.

Cleared the /app/hadoop/tmp folder more than twice.

```
2018-07-10 19:02:12,715 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.net.BindException: Port in use: localhost:0
at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.constructBindException(HttpServer2.java:1014)
at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.bindForSinglePort(HttpServer2.java:1037)
at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.openListeners(HttpServer2.java:1094)
at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:951)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.web.DatanodeHttpServer.<init>(DatanodeHttpServer.java:135)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startInfoServer(DataNode.java:962)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:1370)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:495)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2695)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2598)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2645)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2789)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2813)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.bindListener(HttpServer2.java:1002)
at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.bindForSinglePort(HttpServer2.java:1033)
... 11 more
2018-07-10 19:02:12,726 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.net.BindException: Port in use: localhost:0
2018-07-10 19:02:12,736 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Comment: `java.net.BindException: Port in use: localhost:0` The port for the app is already in use. Check your running processes.

Comment: any specific command to get the processes specific to datanode ? i tried ps -ef |grep hadoop | grep -P 'datanode'  , it didnt help

Comment: $ps -ef | grep  datanode ,:----

"pangea 17700 15735 0 12:18 pts/18 0:00:00 grep --color=auto datanode"      
should i kill this process and try ?

Comment: You can't kill a grep process. Please edit your question to include your Hadoop XML files and Hadoop version